# How to make symfony display exceptions in functional testing with phpunit

Tags: symfony, phpunit

When I run unit tests with PhpUnit in console all exceptions are display immediately there. However when I moved to functional testing I cannot see exceptions which occur.

First I tried symfony `WebTestCase` as it was said [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/testing.html). So I called `$client` with needed parameters and I have a response. But it took time to me to understand that this behaviour is just like I manually open a page I want to test. And a response from `$client->request` contains text (html). Yes errors are show there but there are pretty much html and it is really hard to find the exception. Yes, I can use `$crawler->filter('.text-exception')->first()->text()` but I want so that exception was visible like in unit test. When I tested commands exceptions are shown by PhpUnit as well as normal.

I tried to copy code from `web/app_dev.php` to test case. But it is the same. I have only html response.

So how can I make it so that PhpUnit display exceptions in functional testing like in unit testing?

Answer (score 6):

You can use profiler to do it:

```
$client->enableProfiler();
$client->request('GET', '/');
$profile = $client->getProfile();
$exceptionProfile = $profile->getCollector('exception');

if ($exceptionProfile->hasException()) {
    $message = sprintf(
        "No exception was expected but got '%s' with message '%s'. Trace:\n%s",
        get_class($exceptionProfile->getException()),
        $exceptionProfile->getMessage(),
        $exceptionProfile->getException()->getTraceAsString()
    );
    throw new AssertionFailedError($message);
}
```

Comment: Added. Please see `HttpKernel/DataCollector/ExceptionDataCollector.php` for more details.